# Как найти n делителей факториала?

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика

Есть факториал числа(n!). Как найти n делителей  факториала, чтобы их сумма была рана факториалу

Пример:

```
3! = 1*2*3 = 6 = 1+2+3 (1, 2, 3 — делители 6)
4! = 1*2*3*4 = 24 = 1+3+8+12  (1, 3, 8, 12 — делители 24)
```

Comment: А желательно при этом иметь быстроработающий алгоритм, или же ограничений по времени/памяти нету?

Comment: 60+30+15+12+3=120, 360+180+90+45+30+15=720, 2520+1260+630+315+252+56+7=5040 и это последний, где хвост больше 2.

Comment: Нет, я неправ. https://ideone.com/HILvoN Хотя чую, там что-то простое можно вписать.

Comment: Нужно ли, чтобы делители в сумме были попарно различны или `3! = 2 + 2 + 2` является корректным разложением?

Comment: Все делители должны быть различными

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть `N! = sum(a[i])`, тогда `(N + 1)! = (N + 1) * sum(a[i])`. Причем так как `a[i]` делит `N!`, то `(n + 1) * a[i]` делит `(N + 1)!`. Таким образом, по разложению `N!` в сумму `N` делителей мы можем построить разложение `(N + 1)!` в сумму `N` делителей. Осталось как-то добавить один делитель.

Рассмотрим первые разложения:

- `3! = 3  + 2  + 1`
- `4! = 12 + 8  + 3  + 1`
- `5! = 60 + 40 + 15 + 4 + 1`

Пусть минимальным делителем в разложении `N` будет `1`, тогда в разложении `(N + 1)!` на `N` делителей минимальным будет `N + 1`. Причем его можно разбить на сумму `N` и `1`, которые очевидно являются делителями `(N + 1)!` и при этом не встречаются в разложении до этого, так как меньше `N + 1`, который был минимальным.

Получаем следующий алгоритм:

```
N = 10
a = [3, 2, 1]
for n in range(3,  N):
    for i in range(n):
        a[i] *= n + 1
    a[i] -= 1
    a.append(1)
print(a) #[1814400, 1209600, 453600, 120960, 25200, 4320, 630, 80, 9, 1]

# CHECK
from math import factorial
F = factorial(N)
print(sum(a) == F and len(a) == N and len(set(a)) == N and all(F % i == 0 for i in a)) #True
```

Comment: ````Великолепно!````

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import factorial, ceil, sqrt

numb = int(input('Введите число: '))
```

находим факториал введенного числа

```
a = factorial(numb)
```

функция нахождения делителей

```
def get_all_dividers(num):

    first_half_dividers = [x for x in range(1, ceil(sqrt(num)) + 1)
                       if num % x == 0]

    second_half_dividers = [int(num / x) for x in      reversed(first_half_dividers)
                        if int(num / x) not in first_half_dividers]

    return first_half_dividers + second_half_dividers

list_of_fact = get_all_dividers(a)
```

Удаляем последний элемент списка, иначе он будет выводится в конце при выводе всех вариантов

```
del list_of_fact[-1]


def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    if s == target:
        print(partial)
    if s >= target:
        return 

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
```

выводим все возможные комбинации сумм делителей

```
 subset_sum(list_of_fact, a)
```